# Finding limit as $t\to \infty$ of z(t) for a 3x3 inhomogenous ODE system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, mathematical-modeling

Given the 3x3 linear ODE system describing the dynamic of toxic chemical exchanges in the body
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x'(t)&= -(k_{xy}+u) \cdot x(t) + k_{yx} \cdot y(t) + D\\
y'(t) &= k_{xy}\cdot x(t) -(k_{yx} + k_{yz} + \nu)\cdot y(t) + k_{zy} \cdot z(t)\\
z'(t) &= k_{yz} \cdot y(t) - k_{zy} \cdot z(t)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

with $k_{xy}, k_{yx},k_{yz}, k_{zy}, \nu, u, D$ positive constant and $x,y,z$ the concentration in the blood, tissues and bones respectively.

I want to find the limit as $t \to \infty$ of $z(t)$

I can rewrite this system like
\begin{align*}
       \begin{pmatrix}
            x'(t)\\
            y'(t)\\
            z'(t)
        \end{pmatrix} = 
        \begin{pmatrix}
            -(k_{xy}+u) & k_{yx} & 0\\
            k_{xy} & -(k_{yx}+ k_{yz}+\nu) & k_{zy}\\
            0 & k_{yz}  & -k_{zy}
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
           x(t)\\
            y(t)\\
            z(t)
        \end{pmatrix}
        +
        \begin{pmatrix}
            D \\
            0\\
            0
        \end{pmatrix}
    \end{align*}
I tried diagonalizing the matrix to find the general solution but it doesn't seem to give anything to work with. I was thinking about finding a fixed point but then I can't really say if it is stable or not.

*Is there a way to find the limit without finding the general solution of the system? If not, how could I find the solution?*

Comment: in 1-D, equations of the type $x'=Ax+D$ are solved using an integrating factor

Comment: The system is $\dot X = A X + X_0$. The monic characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^3 + a_2 \lambda^2 + a_1 \lambda + a_0$ with $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_1 a_2 - a_0$ positive (after expanding, $a_1 a_2 - a_0$ is a sum of positive terms). Therefore $A$ is a stable matrix and $\lim_{t \to \infty} X = -A^{-1} X_0$.